# response undefined when using jest mock to test axios in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, axios, jestjs

I have tried lots of answers to similar questions, but none of them helps. (the comments are what I have tried. attempts are separated by a blank line. I have stuck here for almost a week, trying to improve the coverage by testing the .then part of the Axios request. really cannot figure out which part goes wrong.

### code here

> __ mocks __/axios.js:

```
export default {
    get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: {} })),
    post: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve())
}
```

> getInfo method to be tested:

```
getInfo () {
      axios.get('/')
        .then((response) => {
          this.form.sid = response.data.data.basic_info.username
          this.form.name = response.data.data.basic_info.name
          this.form.tel = response.data.data.basic_info.mobile_number
          this.form.email = response.data.data.basic_info.email
          return response.data
        }).catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error)
        })
    }
```

> test code:

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import InfoForm from '@/components/InfoForm'

//attempt 1
import axios from 'axios';
jest.mock('axios')

//attempt 2
// import axios from './__mocks__/axios'
// jest.mock('axios')

//attempt 3
// import axios from './__mocks__/axios'
// jest.mock("axios", () => ({
//     post: jest.fn((_url, _body) => {
//       url = _url
//       body = _body 
//       return Promise.resolve()
//     }),
//     get: jest.fn(() => {
//         return Promise.resolve()
//       })
//   }))

//attempt 4
// import axios from "axios"

//...
//describe part is skipped here

    it('test method: getInfo', async () => {
        const mockAxiosGet = jest.spyOn(axios, "get")
        mockAxiosGet.mockResolvedValue(() =>
            Promise.resolve({
                data: {
                    basic_info: {
                        username: 'aName',
                        name: 'aNAME',
                        mobile_number: '12222222222',
                        email: 'amail@em.com'
                    }
                }
            })
    )

        const response = await wrapper.vm.getInfo()
        expect(response).toBeDefined() // error(plz see error message below)
    })
```

> error message:

```
Ensure that a variable is not undefined.

InfoForm.vue test > test method: getInfo
-----
Error: expect(received).toBeDefined()

Received: undefined Jest
```

**any help is highly appreciated!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getInfo` is a common pitfall with promises. Promises shouldn't be encapsulated and should be returned from a function that contains them in order for them to be chained later. Even if this isn't currently needed, this may be needed later for a function to be composed or tested. The only reason to not do this is that a callback may need a specific signature that doesn't allow to return promise object.

It should be:

```
getInfo () {
   return axios.get('/')
   ...
```

Comment: thank you! sadly still undefined :( I also tried to convert getInfo into async function and use try block to do the axios, but don't have the luck to work.

Comment: Add `expect(axios.get).toBeCalledWith('/')` to make it more specific. If it passes, the only possibility for it to be undefined is that it enters `catch` and you didn't notice console output. It's `response.data.data.basic_info` that is expected to cause an error, you didn't mock it with nested `data` objects.

Comment: weird thing happens as `expect(mockAxiosGet).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/')` passes, however, when i add another `data: {}` to inclose the current `data:{ basic_info:{...}}` in `mockAxiosGet.mockResolvedValue` part, it gives me undefined. but when I remove the `catch` and `console.log(error)`, it gives me 
 `TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined `

Comment: I see. It should be `mockAxiosGet.mockResolvedValue({ data : ...`. It seems that you mocked it the same way as `mockImplementation` by mistake.